# Altering permission to prevent editing of a file in Windows

Tags: windows, permissions, active-directory

We have a proprietary Windows financial program that exports a text file periodically. This file is extracted to a Windows directory by creating a series of temporary files & finally after removing these creates the final file. I'd like the file/directory to allow read/writes/deletes but no editing of a file once it has been created, I've messed about with Windows permissions with no success, does anyone have any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: How could you allow writes, but disallow editing? Do you mean that want it to be possible to append the file, but not edit earlier contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> allow read/writes/deletes but no editing

As far as I know, Windows/NTFS does not distinguish between writes and edits.

> does anyone have any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Configure the program to export to a non-shared folder. Use something like robocopy to watch that folder, copy files to a shared folder with restricted permissions. Give robocopy elevated permissions (e.g. run as administrator).